# How to associate the Existing Surface to MediaCodec encoder surface?

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, opengl-es-2.0, android-mediacodec

I am bit confused after reading lot of resources in the internet.

1) I have a TextureView in the Application. ((tv))

2) I have associated SurfaceTextureLister to ((tv)).

```
    tv.setSurfaceTextureListener(new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {

 public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {

     mySurface  = new Surface(surface);   => This surface is sent to native layer.
    ....
    }
```

3) Passing this **mySurface** surface into the native, I get ANativeWindow for this surface, and use **ANativeWindow_lock** and **ANativeWindow_unlockAndPost** to copy the data into the surface.

So far so good. it is displaying the data what i have copied into the ANativeWindow.

**Now, i want to record all these frames into into MP4 format in a file.**

**What i did?**

1)

I have used the below link for the reference:

http://www.bigflake.com/mediacodec/EncodeAndMuxTest.java.txt

2)

I have retrieived a surface from the mediacodec encoder, and passed to the native to copy the same way as i have copied into the display surface. I see no output in the mp4 file. just a black screen.

**QUESTION:**

1)  Is this the right approach ?  what i mean is you have a raw data, 
    copy the this data into two surfaces,   one has come from application TextureView, and the other one is from mediacodec encoder surface.

2) 
Or, Did i overlook any other easy way of recording the data into mp4 format ?

3)
Or, Any concepts did  i miss completely to look at ?

Kindly provide your valuable input.

Comment: Does the recorded video have multiple frames that are black, or is it just empty? Your approach is, in theory, sound. FWIW, the "record GL app" activity in Grafika (https://github.com/google/grafika) is probably a better source for sample code. For API 21+ you can get a Surface from MediaRecorder, rather than MediaCodec, which will make your life much easier.

Comment: Hi Fadden, Thanks for your reply. The recorded video i am able to play with vlc player for the duration it is recorded. But  the screen is blank as i said earlier. The interesting part is If i use OpenGL commands to generate a frames as in the mentioned example, i see the output, But only the issue is when i do the direct copy to buffer retrieved from ANativeWindow reference.  Please pass on if you have any comments.